# Sort posts by category and date using php and custom query

Tags: php, wp-query, query, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I am using Elementor Pro and Advanced Queries and also ACF for custom date. I have 2 types of posts that are events - event 1 and event 2.
I have an event calendar on the first page showcasing the upcoming event by date (ASC) using custom PHP and Advanced Queries = which works perfectly. BUT as one of the event types is more expensive (better for business) I need it to be shown by the date first. To sum it up I need the events to be showcased like this:

Event 1 (by ASC):

- August 1
- August 2
- Aust 3

Follong in the same post list (by ASC):

Event 2:

- August 2
- August 4
- August 8

I also want to state that I mostly work with Elementor Pro only and no PHP, I have o experience in that so I am just searching on the internet for codes to help solve my problem.

This is the code I used and that worked to list it by date using ACF and Advanced Querie ID:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
    
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'datums' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
  $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

});
```

Then I found something that would match on the internet like this:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
    
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'datums' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
$tax_query = array(
   
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'retriti'
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'visas-meditacijas'
    ),
);
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

  $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

});
```

But then the events disappeared at all...

I tried to find different codes online for this as well but thet do not seem to work for my custom filter by date anymore... Please help me - I am lost and want to cry :D